# how to add new column(not exist) in select result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table :

```
name   dep_id   age
admin  1         22  
admin2 1         23
admi   2         24
ad     2         22
aa     2         23
```

i want to return a result that contain new column called " dep_num " and this column not exist in the main table , and its count the same dep_id , i mean admin and admin2 have the same dep_id so its contain 1,2 and then admi have differnet dep_id so its count from the first 1 and so .. the resut like :

```
dep_num       name   dep_id   age
1             admin  1         22  
2             admin2 1         23
1             admi   2         24
2             ad     2         22
3             aa     2         23
```

Comment: How do you decide 1 should be assigned to `admin` and not `admin2`. Similarly why 1 for  `admi` and not for `ad`?

Comment: @KaushikNayak , coz its comes first so 1 should be for admin and admin 2 ,

Comment: It does not matter how it "comes first". Databases do not maintain any order of rows unless you specify an explicit "Order By". Is there an ID column apart from the one's you've shown? Does it have the same incrementing order as the order of the rows shown?

Comment: @KaushikNayak , yeah assume that ,

Comment: You may then use `row_number() OVER ( partition by dep_id ORDER BY id_column) as  dep_num`

Comment: @KaushikNayak , can u give me some details about ur sol ? why use over ? or row_number ?

Comment: Well that's how we write analytic functions. Google it and explore more about how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dep_id ORDER BY id) dept_num,
  name,
  dep_id,
  age
from table
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no way to say why admin & admin2 should be 1 and 2 and not vice versa. `ROWNUM` doesn't guarantee you that the result will be same each time.

Comment: Yes Kaushik understood ... as you mentioned some key column should be there to get same output everytime . @juslearn2 please look for any key column

Comment: @kanagaraj assume that they have an column id , what is the solution ?

Comment: just edited to include that column id in order by so that everytime same output

Comment: @kanagaraj i dont undersand u

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the table's name is `table_deps`:

```
alter table table_deps
add (dep_num int default 0);

update table_deps d
set dep_num = 1 + (select count(*)
                   from table_deps p 
                   where p.dep_id = d.dep_id
                   and p.name < d.name);
```

Not sure whether the UPDATE works.